# Comparing Dates in a User Defined Function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, user-defined-functions

I am setting up a user defined function which takes in a cell, which contains a date and checks if that date is more than two days ago.

The input cell is not formatted to 'Date' but does contains a date in the format DD-MMM-YYYY.

```
Function testFun(endDateCell As Range)
    
    If DateDiff("d", CDate(endDateCell.Value), Now) > 2 Then
        testFun = "Check"
    Else
        testFun = "Ok"
    End If

End Function
```

The function is always returning #VALUE!

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does the cell contain a *real* date or a *string* that just looks like a date?

Comment: Probably a Type Mismatch on `CDate(endDateCell.Value)` but you can debug further by calling this function from a subroutine.

Comment: You need to see if vba can parse the date.  In the immediate window try just the `CDate(...)` where `...` is the cell reference.

Comment: @ScottCraner: I have regional settings German and CDate accepts german month names, but not english. And it expects the order to be day / month / year *or* year / month / day, but not month / day / year

Comment: Same here. That's why I insist that a date is stored as date in Excel. And if it comes from any kind of input (input box, text file import...), I try to convert it manually.

Comment: And it may not be anything to do with the date conversion, but instead may be that the order in the DateDiff is wrong. The first Date must be after the second date.

Comment: It is a string that looks like a date (22-Mar-2021). If I pass `?CDate(...)` in the Immediate Window, I received 22.03.2021. If I pass `?Now` I receive 23.03.2021 20:30:15. I also changed the order in the `DateDiff` still no result

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfectly for me when I set EndDateCell as cell B2 which contains the date "02-Feb-2020". Is there an issue with how you are calling the function or how you defined your variables? Here is what I did that worked.

```
    Sub func()
    Dim tval As String, enddatecell As Range
    
    Set enddatecell = Sheets("test").Cells(2, 2) 'or user defined cell
    enddatecell.NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"

    tval = testFun(enddatecell) 
    
    End Sub
    '__________________________________________

    Function testFun(enddatecell As Range)
        
        If DateDiff("d", CDate(enddatecell.Value), Now) > 2 Then
            testFun = "Check"
        Else
            testFun = "Ok"
        End If
    
    End Function
```

Comment: I set up a subroutine in order to try to debug the function. I do have a Type Mismatch in `CDate(enddatecell.Value)`, the value of the cell is a string. But why can't `CDate` convert the value to a date type?

Comment: I also tried to first assign the string in the cell to a str variable and then pass the variable through `CDate` and assign the result to a new variable which was set to type `Date` before. This also turns a Type Mismatch.

Comment: Can you add `enddatecell.NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"` after setting enddatecell to a range? I updated the code in my answer

Comment: I tried your suggestions, this the same error was returned. I ended up converting the dates to strings and performing a simple "is equal to" check. It is not as flexible, but solved my problem.Thank you very much for your help!